# How to create session IDs for a self service sequence on website data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope the title is not too vague or confusing, but I haven't found a solution that can help me yet.

I have a dataset where we log the self service of a customer on a website. The customer will start a self service (e.g. Upgrade my subscription), where the data will log every step they reach, until they hopefully finish the self service. For every self service session, there will be a **Start** tag and then the tagged steps the customer finishes. If the customer goes through the self service in one go, it could look like this:

[image]

Here, the ID is the customer ID (not a session ID), the timestamp that the step occoured, and the step the customer reached on the timestamp.
If the customer restarts for some reason (session time out, customer made a mistake or similar), the self service would restart and the data would look like this:

[image]

What I need, is to make a new column that groups the steps into assumed sessions (There are no session IDs for a started self service). If there is a new **Start** tag, it is assumed that this is a new session.  For example, the above data could look like this:

[image]

Can anyone help med?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a windowed conditional aggregate:

```sql
COUNT(CASE Label WHEN 'Start' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TimeStamp
                                                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEEDING AND CURRRENT ROW) AS Session
```

Comment: Perfect. That solved my problem (it had two spelling errors but I got the point). Thank you so much :)